# Retrying tests on failure in path.FunSpec in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

The recommended way to handle this in regular [FunSpec](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/FunSpec.html) is to override `withFixture`. However, [this is not an option](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/path/FunSpec.html) in `path.FunSpec`.

Is there a clean way to retry tests a set amount of times on failure? The only solution I have at the moment is to create a utility function that wraps every test individually, but this doesn't seem that great.

Comment: Hey, Nequol! Could you clarify what you mean by "rerun tests for all tests that use the same base"? withFixture is used to setup some common code that initializes objects that are shared by all the tests in a suite. It has nothing to do with rerunning tests.

Comment: Hi there Andrei, a common pattern for "retrying" a test on failure seems to be to override withFixture to restart the test on a failure result. This also seems to be whats recommended in the documentation. To do this for a whole group of suites, I'm thinking we would use a base spec which all other suites would extend, which would then get this overridden withFixture. I will clarify in the question that its for retrying on failure.